# Group by and distinct by lambda

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying group by and take distinct values from the result. In the code below `ptionid` gives enumerable of `int[1]`, I want to have distinct values in `ptionid`.

I tried `ptionid = optid.Distinct()` butit gives null values.

```
var result = slnlist.GroupBy( (a) => a.ID,
(a) => a.ParamID,
(rpid, opid) =>
new
{
    id = rpid,
    ptionid = optid.Distinct().Select((x)=>x)
}
);
```

I was able to get distinct values but need to know how to get them into a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you want the inner `ptionid` in dictionary or the final `result`?

Comment: Thanks nawfal.Yes I want the whole result in dictionary I got the answer from [Todictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611126/using-todictionary)in which ToDictionary accepts two lambdas.

Comment: Glad you found one. Indeed the way to go.