# How to Read Lines from File and Turn Array of Strings into Dictionary in C# with line Number as Key?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to read lines from a file (whose size is unknown) and convert the array values that start with "A" into a `Dictionary` with the line number as the key and the line contents as the value. I'm trying to think of a way of doing this without iterating over the array as that would be slow for large files. I'm currently putting in the line's `hashcode` (assuming no duplicates, but I can use `.Distinct` if needed) as the key but get an error as shown below the code:

Code:

```
Dictionary<int, string> lines = File
  .ReadLines(inputFilePath)
  .Select(x => x.StartsWith("A"))
  .ToDictionary(x => x.GetHashCode, x => x.ToString());
```

The `ToDictionary` has the red error line with the following message:
*"The Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly"*

In that line, I'm just trying to get some distinct value for each Key, but I would like to get the line number if possible. I feel it's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: What would be the advantage of a dictionary over an array? In an array, the line number would be the index.

Comment: @realbart The file may be extremely large, and the uses for the returned lines isn't quite known, so I figured it'd be easier to iterate over a dictionary than an array. It's sort of violating YAGNI, but we know files may be very large and I'm hoping this would be more performant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .ToDictionary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611126/using-todictionary)

Comment: @HassanMonjezi That question is similar, but they're wanting to get the number of letters occurring in a string and use that as the key and I'm not sure if they're reading from a file. Dmitry's answer below solved the issue I was having. Thank you for the reference!

Comment: If the file can be very big then not using LINQ but a traditional "while" loop will provide better performance (user fewer memory)

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you for the heads up, I'll look into that and refactor appropriately. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: I have extended my answer to contain a solution that needs fewer memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from the example. You have a file like this:

```
Abracadabra
Boo-zoo
Sausages
Alakazam
```

And you want to obtain a dictionay: value is a file line which starts from `A`,
key is `1, 2, 3, ...`

```
{1, "Abracadabra"}
{2, "Alakazam"}
```

So we can do it like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> lines = File
  .ReadLines(inputFilePath)
  .Where(line => line.StartsWith("A"))
  .Select((value, index) => (value, index))
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index + 1, pair => pair.value);
```

The little trick is to obtain line index which we can do with a help of `Select`:

```
  .Select((value, index) => (value, index))
```

If you want to use line index *before filtration*, i.e.

```
{0, "Abracadabra"}
{3, "Alakazam"}
```

move `Select` ahead:

```
Dictionary<int, string> lines = File
  .ReadLines(inputFilePath)
  .Select((value, index) => (value, index))
  .Where(pair => pair.value.StartsWith("A"))
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index + 1, pair => pair.value);
```

Comment: @NineBerry: it's unclear for me what index should be used; so I've provided both options (after and before filtration) with examples

Comment: Ahh, I think that should do it. So for the Select statement, that value, index are just inherent in the code where we can snag those indices/values from? That's good to know thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int, string> lines = 
    File.ReadLines(inputFilePath).
    Select((value, number) => (value, number)).
    Where(x => x.value.StartsWith("A")).
    ToDictionary(x => x.number + 1, x => x.value);
```

Explanation:

```
Select((value, number) => (value, number))
```

Turns the line number and the line into a tuple.

```
Where(x => x.value.StartsWith("A")).
```

Applies the filter, filtering out the lines that don't start with A

```
ToDictionary(x => x.number + 1, x => x.value)
```

Turns the list of tuples into a dictionary. We add +1 to the line number because the internal count is 0-based.

---

If the file is bigger, the previous approach is not so good because it may load more content into memory at once and do a lot of object creation for every line. A traditional while loop will reduce memory use drastically.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(inputFilePath))
{
    string line;
    int lineNumber = 0;

    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lineNumber++;
        if (line.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            dict.Add(lineNumber, line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, the transformation into a tuple was very helpful/informative.